# Socket.io + node.js + IIS hangs/ Freeze issue

Tags: node.js, performance, iis, websocket, socket.io

I have implemented the socket.io in my application. I will explain my application first, after that I will explain my issue.

My application is node-based application which hosted via IIS with reversed proxy mechanism.
I have implemented Socket.io in my application where socket.io client connects to server with below code.

**Client Code:**

```
    try {
let path = window.location.pathname;
path = path.substring( 0, path.lastIndexOf( "/" ) );
window.SocketConnection = io && io.connect( "/", { path: path + "/socket.io" } );
} catch( exception ) {
console.error( exception );
}
```

The above code will execute once, my application loads.

**Server Code:**

```
    // Socket connection options.
const SocketOptions = {
pingTimeout: 60000,
maxHttpBufferSize: 1024 * 1024 * 48,
transports: [ "polling", "websocket" ]
};

// Initialize the Socket connection with required parameters.
io = socketIO( server, SocketOptions );
```

**Problem:**
Now the issue is, if more number clients (around 3K connection) connected to server then, IIS hangs and freezed.

**My question:**
The provided information may be insufficient to answer my question, but it would be helpful if you answer my below questions.

1. What is the best way to handle this kind of IIS hang/ freeze on high
   load?
2. Do I need to use any special Socke.io client/server option to
   reduce this kind of load issue?

By,
Sarath Kumar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for

> 1. What is the best way to handle this kind of IIS hang/ freeze on high load?

=> first check system memory to cache memory not becoming too high.

=> try to optimize your code for performance.

=> some time due to the server can't able to handle the heavy load of requests.
=> try to multiple servers to distribute your server request load.

> 2. Do I need to use any special Socke.io client/server option to reduce this kind of load issue?

=> yes you can do it. like multiple Socket servers for reducing heavy load at a time.you can use Loadbalancer.